# Failed to get details of the deployment ID error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I tried to change the version of my gmail addon before submitting it but I keep getting this error *Failed to get details of the deployment ID*.

Steps that I've done:

1. I managed to add a version to the submit form
2. My submission got rejected
3. I made some changes to the addon's code
4. I tried to change the addon's deployment ID to the new version but I got this error instead

[image: This is what the error looks like.]

Comment: Can you explain more in detail the steps you performed? Maybe also add some screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

### This kind of error usually appears in case of a wrong `Deployment ID`

- Common causes are e.g. spaces introduced before or after the Id.
- Another possibility is that the Apps Script project is bound, while for a Google Workspace Add-on it needs to be a standalone script.
- It is also possible that MarketSpace SDK does not find the script because the owner of the GCP project and the Apps Script file are not the same person.
- While the following behavior would result in a different error than yours - for completion sake:

  You also need to make sure that the Apps Script is tied to a Standard GCP project - namely the one to which the Add-On belongs, and that it is the only Apps Script project bound to this GCP project